# JSON Schema for JSON:API-- how to add "type" keyword for JSON:API Type

Tags: jsonschema, json-api

I have a webapp that communicates with a different server via JSON:API.  I am trying to use [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org) via [Ajv](https://ajv.js.org) in the webapp to validate the JSON from the server (Drupal 10 JSON:API).

However, JSON:API returns a `type` key:

```
{
  "type": "article",
  "id": "1",
}
```

And JSON Schema uses `type` to mean "the type to enforce":

```
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "description": "uuid",
      "type": "string"
    },
```

So for the output of `"type": "article"`, how can I specify in JSON Schema that there should be a property named `type`?  The type keyword is reserved, so how do I get around that?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me.  You can just use `type` normally-- as long as it is in the proper place, JSON Schema can process it correctly:

```
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "description": "uuid",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    }
```

Comment: Yes.  `type` as a property to validate in the instance is completely independent of the `type` keyword in a schema.  